# Manage a 4 dimensional array or a 5 dimensional with foreach statement in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a really bad time right now, since everyone on the internet is saying that PHP supports multidimensional arrays that are two, three, four, five, or more levels deep. However, arrays more than three levels deep are hard to manage for most people. So I can't find someone to help me.

A very simple example below

```
  $documents = array(
    array(
         "name"=>"Markos",
        "lastname"=>"papadopoulos",
        "country"=>"Greece",
        "nationality"=>"greek",
        "job"=>"web developer",
        "hobbies"=>array(
                "sports"=>"boxing",
                "others"=>array(
                        "freetime"=>"watching Tv"
                )
        )

    )
);

foreach($documents as $document){
    echo $document['name']."<br>"
        .$document['lastname']."<br>"
        .$document['country']."<br>"
        .$document['nationality']."<br>"
        .$document['job']."<br>";

            foreach ($document['hobbies'] as $key=>$value){
                echo $key." ".$value."<br>";

                    foreach ($value['others'] as $subkey=>$subvalue){
                        echo $subkey['freetime'];
                    }

                }
}
```

I am stuck, I can't display the `"others"=>array("freetime"=>"watching tv")` can anyone advice me? And if I had also another array in the `"others"=>array("freetime"=>"watching tv")`, how could I display that array to? I am trying to learn the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, `foreach` actually have two syntaxes:

1. `foreach($array as $element)` this might means `$element` ends up being an array
2. `foreach($array as $key => $value)` this means that `key` will never be an array, it is what the key, so what you have before the `=>` in your array, while `$value` can be an array.

Here is the way to follow the first syntax, mind that you don't even have to nest `foreach` here, as pointed out by [@Nathanael's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158302/manage-a-4-dimensional-array-or-a-5-dimensional-with-foreach-statement-in-php#comment109933994_62158464) what you have in your array is mostly scalar, not really nested arrays.

```php
foreach($documents as $document){
  echo $document['name']."<br>".
    $document['lastname']."<br>".
    $document['country']."<br>".
    $document['nationality']."<br>".
    $document['job']."<br>".
    $document['job']."<br>".
    $document['hobbies']['sports']."<br>".
    $document['hobbies']['others']['freetime'];
}
```

If you want to go in the second syntax, then it would be even better to make a [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)):

```php
function display_multi_level_array($array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)) {
       display_multi_level_array($value);
       continue;
    }

    echo $key." ".$value."<br>";
  } 
}

display_multi_level_array($documents);
```

Comment: the second syntax is working and it is very usefull

Comment: the first syntax it's not working..i accept your question cause the second was very usefull.. specially for 7-8 dimensional arrays and above

Comment: Yes the first one was buggy, it was just code out of my head. It is tested and working in the edit :)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($documents as $key) {
echo $key['name']. '<br>';
echo $key['lastname']. '<br>';
echo $key['country']. '<br>';
echo $key['nationality']. '<br>';
echo $key['job']. '<br>';
echo $key['hobbies']['sports']. '<br>';
echo $key['hobbies']['others']['freetime']. '<br>';
}
```

output will be
Markos
papadopoulos
Greece
greek
web developer
boxing
watching Tv

Comment: i have to admit your way is very simple and easy to understand. Also put the `}` :P

Answer (score 2):

try

```
foreach($documents as $document){
echo $document['name']."<br>"
    .$document['lastname']."<br>"
    .$document['country']."<br>"
    .$document['nationality']."<br>"
    .$document['job']."<br>";

        foreach ($document['hobbies'] as $key=>$value){
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $subkey=>$subvalue){
                    echo $subvalue;
                }
            } else {
                echo $key." ".$value."<br>";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: so  in order to get the next information we have to use `if (is_array($value))`  to direct the programm?

Comment: No, the array you are using has mixed value types, you are mixing scalar values and arrays in the same array, which you can do, but then you have to test the type of the value before handling it